# Can i convert the guest OS to main OS?

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my computer and windows XP as guest OS using virtual box. Can i change the main OS to XP without having to format Ubuntu and installing Windows XP?

Comment: What is the image format? I believe this is possible using VMware converter tools, but am not sure whether those are free.

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what you want, but check if it can help: http://askubuntu.com/a/308903/72576