# Dualboot Ubuntu to VirtualBox VDI migration

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, virtualbox

I'm trying to migrate my current install to a virtualbox so that I can use it to recover some preferences/data when I install Bionic on my laptop. I currently dualboot my system and I have my Ubuntu partition in `/dev/sda7`. I tried converting it to a vdi by following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34802/convert-my-physical-operating-system-to-a-virtualbox-disk). However, it looks like my boot partition is separate and I can't boot into the vdi. I used another virtualbox to chroot into this system and do `grub-install`. It failed due to the lack of a valid directory. How do I fix this issue and migrate my physical Ubuntu to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying the contents of your boot directory to /boot on the root of the drive you want to boot from?

This will copy the various kernels and other files grub may need.

Then try and install grub with grub-install again.