# I can't start a Virtual Machine from a VDI file obtained by VBoxManage convertdd

Tags: boot, virtualbox, lubuntu, vdi

I have followed instructions showed by [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34802/convert-my-physical-operating-system-to-a-virtualbox-disk) and in particular I started with the following `dd` command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=/path/to/file/img/my-bootable-lubuntu.img
```

The source for the `dd` command is a SD card (`/dev/sde`) with lubuntu 22.04 correctly installed and bootable on its original hardware (an embedded system). In the SD card are present 2 partitions: the boot partition and the root partition with all the lubuntu distribution.

After `dd` I have executed commands:

```
> cd /path/to/file/img

> VBoxManage convertdd my-bootable-lubuntu.img my-bootable-lubuntu.vdi --format VDI
```

By the previous command I get the file `my-bootable-lubuntu.vdi`.

I would like to create a VirtualBox virtual machine by this `.vdi` file, so I have added it as an Hard-Disk for the new virtual machine as showed in the following picture:

[image]

When I try to start the virtual machine I immediately obtain the error:

> FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted

What could be the problem?

Comment: To create a VMDK which links to /dev/sde: `sudo VBoxManage createmedium disk --filename my.vmdk --format=VMDK --variant RawDisk --property RawDrive=/dev/sde`. To link to the image perhaps it's safe to simply edit the VMDK file but I cannot gurantee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality everything works. My mistake was booting the Virtual Machine by the `Start` button (see image below):

[image]

before pressing the `OK` button present in the tab used to add the VDI disk to the SATA controller (see image below):

[image]

Perhaps I have repeated this error more than one time. By pressing correctly the button `OK` all starts working.

So the procedure showed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34802/convert-my-physical-operating-system-to-a-virtualbox-disk/34879#34879) works perfectly.